# I Can't Find my Collection on OpenSea Testnet

Tags: hardhat, opensea

I recently deployed a smart contract to the testnet. You are able to buy NFTs using fake eth. I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/scrappy-squirrels/tutorial-writing-an-nft-collectible-smart-contract-9c7e235e96da) but when I deploy my contract to the testnet (new Alchemy App, New API key, New Contract Name) I can't see it on the OpenSea testnet, despite putting in the contract address. I am able to see it on Etherscan [here](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x32FB1b06cF17eeD17BE14a6312a1dED5CD06a5dB). Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code for NFTCollectibleTest:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;



import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";


contract NFTCollectibleTest is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    uint public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 50;
    uint public constant PRICE = 0.01 ether;
    uint public constant MAX_PER_MINT = 3;
    
    string public baseTokenURI;
    


constructor(string memory baseURI) ERC721("NFTCollectibleTest", "NFTCT"){
setBaseURI(baseURI);
}

function reserveNFTs() public onlyOwner {
uint totalMinted = _tokenIds.current();

require(
    totalMinted.add(3) < MAX_SUPPLY, "Not enough NFTs"
);
for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++){
_mintSingleNFT();
}
}

function _baseURI() internal
                    view
                    virtual
                    override
                    returns (string memory) {
            return baseTokenURI;
}

function setBaseURI(string memory _baseTokenURI) public onlyOwner{
baseTokenURI = _baseTokenURI;
}

function mintNFTs(uint _count) public payable{
    uint totalMinted = _tokenIds.current();
    
    require(
        totalMinted.add(_count) <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Not enough NFTs!"
    );
    require(
        _count >0 && _count <= MAX_PER_MINT,
        "Cannot mint specified number of NFTs(Please enter a valid amount)."
    );
    require(
    msg.value >= PRICE.mul(_count), "Not enough ether to purchase NFTs."
    );
     for (uint i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
            _mintSingleNFT();
     }}
     
     function _mintSingleNFT() private{
     uint newTokenID = _tokenIds.current();
     _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenID);
     _tokenIds.increment();
     }
     
     function tokensOfOwner(address _owner)
            external
            view
            returns (uint[] memory){
            
        uint tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint[] memory tokensId = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        
        for (uint i = 0; i < tokenCount; i++){
        tokensId[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokensId;
            }
            
            
function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    uint balance = address(this).balance;
    require(balance > 0, "No ether left to withdraw.");
    
    (bool success, ) =(msg.sender).call{value: balance}("");
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");
}

}
```

Here is my code for run.js:

```
const { utils } = require("ethers");

async function main() {
    const baseTokenURI = "ipfs://QmVgCMc859nvBnmPV1EAn6Z9CG9GdJS3sYCM1d5xo4XefU/";

    // Get owner/deployer's wallet address
    const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    // Get contract that we want to deploy
    const contractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTCollectibleTest");

    // Deploy contract with the correct constructor arguments
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(baseTokenURI);

    // Wait for this transaction to be mined
    await contract.deployed();

    // Get contract address
    console.log("Contract deployed to:", contract.address);

    // Reserve NFTs
    let txn = await contract.reserveNFTs();
    await txn.wait();
    console.log("3 NFTs have been reserved");

    // Mint 1 NFTs by sending 0.01 ether
    txn = await contract.mintNFTs(3, { value: utils.parseEther('0.03') });
    await txn.wait()

    // Get all token IDs of the owner
    let tokens = await contract.tokensOfOwner(owner.address)
    console.log("Owner has tokens: ", tokens);

}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Here is my code for hardhat.config.js:

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
require('dotenv').config();

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY, ETHERSCAN_API } = process.env;

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: API_URL,
    accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
    
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API
  }
};
```

Here is my public key (wallet address):

```
0xe7eE00Cb67c3eB80937669f593A9FF3a4d3e96b2
```

I'm on the sepolia testnet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The OpenSea testnet only supports the Goeril Ethereum test network, not Sepolia.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2023, they finally added it to their supported testnets!
https://docs.opensea.io/reference/supported-chains